# How can I make tables from a column through conditions?

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a column with keywords and I need to know which are the most used keywords. I have separated them using a delimiter however making them in to a table has become more or less a manual task which I'm looking to avoid. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Sample of the table I get (after using a delimiter to separate the col 2 of original table) is provided below after which the process becomes manual which I'd like to avoid. Do note that the required keywords will always be in one columns. For example, in the attached image of the table, col 3, col 5, col 7, and col 9 contain the keywords.

[image]

Comment: So, you want to count the frequency of your keywords in a column? `table(col)`.

Comment: yes, that's right.